# Видеочат с помощью WebRTC

Tags: потоки-данных, webrtc

Как я могу создать видеочат с помощью WebRTC и создавать рандомные комнаты при каждом новом заходе на сайт, чтобы видеть друг друга в отдельных комнатах? Я видел много примеров веб-сервисов, но нет материалов с подробным описанием. Я пытался создать его, но я вижу только мое лицо и при этом не могу видеть другого человека. Что мне нужно сделать? Может есть что-то готовое с подробным описанием? Спасибо.